# How and Where to add JNDI for Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jndi, connection-pooling

I need the code to add JNDI name to achive connection pooling in hibernate.
I have configured the connetion pooling in Jboss server with the JNDI name as "EmployeeDB"

How to configure it in hibernate.cfg.xml ??

Plez give me the code for hibernate.cfg.xml if i am using Hibernate 4 Final release.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The datasource JDNI name configured in the Jboss server  is specified by the properties `hibernate.connection.datasource`.

The basic `hibernate.cfg.xml` should look like :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration> 
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/EmployeeDB</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Mapped annotated entity-->
        <mapping class="org.hibernate.tutorial.domain.Event"/>

    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you...
I dint know abt the hibernate.connection.datasource

now where to add that??
You mean in the oracle-ds.xml ???
in which tag should i modify???

Comment: `hibernate.connection.datasource ` is for the hibernate configuration file which default file name is `hibernate.cfg.xml`