# Trying to set up Tomcat and JDBC connection pooling: Communications Link Failure

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, jdbc, remote-access

Full error message from the tomcat window:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure)
```

Basically every time I start up tomcat it gets a communications link failure when trying to form a jdbc connection with my mysql database on a remote linux server, (on a private network that I must VPN into) and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how I could go about solving it. As always, thanks for the time and assistance!

**Steps Already Taken**

. Configured MySQL to allow remote connections to the database. I've tried setting the bind-address in my.cnf to 0.0.0.0 and the IP of the server that the database is hosted on, but in both cases the same error. I've added a new user and used the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES command to give that user remote access to the database from 127.0.0.1 and from the IP of the server that the database is hosted on.

. Tried completely deactivating my firewall, to no effect

. From intellij on my local computer I've tried forming a JDBC connection to the database using the set up user and password in the persistence menu. This works when I am already VPNed into the private network, and I am able to see the database just fine.

. Updated the **server.xml** with this Resource tag in my tomcat folder:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
      global="jdbc/mydb"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://(IP-address of the database server):3306/DBname"
      username="user"
      password="password"
      maxActive="10"
      maxIdle="10"
      minIdle="5"
      maxWait="10000"/>
```

. Updated the **context.xml** file in the tomcat folder with this resource link:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb" 
       global="jdbc/mydb"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

. Updated my **hibernate.cfg.xml** file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <!-- For Database Access -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://(IP-address of database server):3306/DBname</property>
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="db-full.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo1"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo2"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo3"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo4"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo5"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo6"/>
    <mapping class="POJOs.Pojo7"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

. Updated my **dispatcher-servlet.xml** as follows:

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc.controllers, data.service, data.DAO" />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://(IP-address of database server):3306/DBname" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="user" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

. Updated my **web.xml** as follows:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<display-name>Web Application</display-name>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/resources/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/springDispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- RESOURCE REF (TRIED RUNNING WITH AND WITHOUT) -->
<!--<resource-ref>-->
    <!--<description>Connection Pool</description>-->
    <!--<res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>-->
    <!--<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>-->
    <!--<res-auth>Container</res-auth>-->
<!--</resource-ref>-->

</web-app>
```

. Updated **pom.xml** as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.procect-name</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.5.49</mysql.connector.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.5.50</mysql.connector.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JDBC Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQL Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson To Convert java to JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application View -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP (Connection Pooling) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering, the reason I couldn't connect is because the private network that I had to VPN into only allowed certain ports to access to the database.

In my case the default MySQL port of 3306 was blocked on that network and had to be changed to one of the allowed ports.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following properties, you would not be required to declare a `JNDI` variable.

```
hibernate.connection.url
hibernate.connection.username
hibernate.connection.password
hibernate.connection.driver_class
```

## Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gocommerce</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping resource="Item.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

If you want to use the `JNDI` approach, then I would suggest this.

Edit/Create file `*path_to_your_tomcat_home*/conf/Catalina/*hostname*/*applicationName*.xml` and then declare the JNDI variable like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" cookies="true">
    <Resource name="datasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://<database-url>/<database-name>"
        username="<username>" password="<password>" />
</Context>
```

And then in you hibernate file, you can specify the datasource as `java:comp/env/datasource`.

Since you have specified the datasource itself, you can skip the `hibernate.connection.url` property.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677332/5766794) for reference.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, using a JNDI resoure is not necessary if you use the four variables you mentioned above. Do all of those need to be set in hibernate.cfg.xml? Or should it be enough that they are specified in the hibernate data source bean in the dispatcher servlet. Currently in the hibernate.cfg.xml I only declare a hibernate.connection.url, hibernate.dialect, and hibernate.connection.driver_class. But after removing the JNDI resource and link from server.xml and context.xml and running, I get the same error. @Jay

Comment: Have you verified that your database is running? Try `mysql -u <username> -p --host = <hostname>` command and see what happens.

Comment: Yea when I run that command I'm able to access the database just fine

Comment: I have edited my answer and added an example in it. Try to use the exact same one and check whether the problem still persist...

Comment: After trying that code in my hibernate.cfg.xml and running i'm getting the same error

Comment: I can provide you configuration for the bean itself. I am travelling right now so that is not possible at this moment. I will get back to you when I'm home.

Comment: So after trying to connect through Ethernet at the location of the private local network where the database server is located, I'm getting a different error that the host I'm trying to connect from is not allowed to access the MySQL server. Regardless of this error, does this indicate that the private server was blocking outside access to tomcat when I was at home?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122856/discussion-between-jay-and-user3792733).

Comment: If you're interested you can check the below answer I posted which resolved my problem. I got some value out of your answer though because it showed me that I did not need to use a JNDI resource and hibernate data source, so thanks and have an upvote! @Jay

Comment: Personally I will not recommend setting up DB directly in hibernate as you showed.  It is giving a lot of unnecessary restriction to your application.  For example, when you want to make use of feature of container (e.g. better pooling, distributed txn), it won't work.  Another example is you cannot mix Hibernate and JDBC in one txn (as by your way, hibernate is getting its own connection, while if you want to use JDBC, you need to get another connection which will results in different connection hence different txn), it is uncommon but not impossible, especially you are using other

Comment: framework that will maintain its own state in DB, e.g. Spring-Batch